# NetworkComms.net very slow sending from Windows by USB to ipad

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin.ios, network-programming, usb

Need to send live video from Windows-7 by USB to iPad at at least 15 frames per second for 512×512 byte frame.

But only seeing < 1 frame per second by USB (and 4-6 fps by WIFI).
 Loop is iPad app uses NetworkComms.SendReceiveObject() to request frame, and Windows app uses NetworkComms.SendObject() to send frame reply.

Can NetworkComms stream 512 x 512 byte frames continually from Windows to iPad without needing a request for each frame?

Seeing 3.6 fps by USB and 30fps by WIFI if sending 100×100 byte frame.
 But at desired frame size 512 x 512, USB is < 1fps, and WIFI is ~6fps.

Strange that WIFI is faster.

Windows app is Visual Studio 2010 C# with NetworkComms.net.
 iPad app is Xamarin Monotouch C# with NetworkComms.net.

Comment: Ah, hah!  NetworkComms.net has UDP for streaming.  I will persue this, and report back help.  Don't worry -- in a closed system, UDP is the solution for highest speed streaming (I've done it on a huge, defense data storage RAID).  Yes, in an open system, UDP is prone to dropped packets due to overrun.  But not in a closed system, if your interrupt buffers are big enough to allow delays due to your other threads.  "Where there's a will, there's a way."

Comment: They also have TCP with optional compression, so I will use that.  NetworkComms.Net has an excellent website with tutorials, examples, the best download product samples I've ever seen, and online API doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use there [UDP broadcasting](http://www.networkcomms.net/udp-broadcasting/) solution to do continuous, asynchronous, one-way streaming, at:
http://www.networkcomms.net/udp-broadcasting/

Or, even better, use their TCP method, which supports compression for even faster speed.  Download their excellent sample and find example code in AdvancedSend.cs file.

WARNING:  Runs extremely slow if running from Visual Studio.  When I run the C# .exe, then I get 44Mbps throughput from Windows-7 to iPad across USB (which is USB2.0 for iPad hardware).

Here's my code:
// VISUAL STUDIO 2010 C# STREAMING TRANSMIT TO IPAD:

for (; ; )      // thread's exec loop
{
        NetworkComms.SendObject("Ultrasound Stream", ultrasound_stream_sourceId, false, frame_to_iPad);
}

// IPAD STREAMING RECEIVER FROM WINDOWS:

NetworkCommsDotNet.NetworkComms.AppendIncomingPacketHandler("Ultrasound Stream",
(packetHeader, connection, incoming_bytes) =>
{
        // your code that processes incoming_bytes goes here.
}, false);